GKE Website sometimes returning 502, sometimes working
I serve a frontend site with Go, and I deployed my service onto GKE using Docker. Sometimes the website loads "http://staging.crcl-app.com", "http://www.staging.crcl-app.com", and sometimes it returns a 502 Bad Gateway. It doesn't seem to be a problem with my deployment, maybe something with Ingress? I have a cloud DNS setup with the domain as well that routes to the "crcl-global" IP I defined in ingress.yaml, I will attach screenshots of those.

deployment.yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: staging-deployment
  namespace: admin-ns
  labels:
    app: staging
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: staging
      tier: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: staging
        tier: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: staging
        image: # removed for stackoverflow
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3001
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz # GKE readinessProbe healthcheck
            port: 3001
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz # GKE livenessProbe healthcheck
            port: 3001
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 20
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: "1"
          requests:
            memory: 256Mi
            cpu: "0.2"



      serviceAccountName: "admin-sa"

ingress.yaml:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: crcl-staging-ingress # name of service 
  namespace: admin-ns # this is the role in GCP it has, we need to give it perms so it can access secret manager, storage, etc. 
  annotations:
    spec.ingressClassName: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: crcl-global # Expose IP
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: crcl-app-cert # Google managed certificates
  labels:
    app: staging
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: crcl-gke-backend
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: www.staging.crcl-app.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: / 
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: crcl-gke-backend
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: api.staging.crcl-app.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: crcl-gke-backend
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: staging.crcl-app.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: crcl-gke-backend
            port:
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: crcl-gke-backend
  namespace: admin-ns
  labels:
    app: staging
spec:
  type: NodePort # Internal staging IP (Routed to by ingress)
  selector:
    app: staging
    tier: web
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 3001



502 Bad Gateway error in Kubernetes relates to several points of failure in the Pod or Service or Ingress. Can you check this link which will help you to debug a 502 error accordingly.

Hello, I debugged it using that article and still the same error. Everything seems to be working perfectly fine. No logs of a 500, my health checks are all functional. Could it be a DNS thing or my Ingress?

As you have mentioned “A record” with TTL value of 300 seconds.A very short TTL for DNS records could lead to inconsistencies, if possible try to  increase the TTL value.
